# Правильно ли обособлен оборот «причем в отличие от Горького»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*В период между мировыми войнами он был Очень Важной Персоной. **Причем в отличие от Горького**, персоной не национального, а планетарного значения* (Б. Акунин).

Присоединительный союз «причем» относится ко всему предложению – соответственно, оборот «в отличие от Горького» нужно или обособлять двумя запятыми или вообще не обособлять. Но здесь (по структуре предложения) надо бы обособить. С другой стороны, не хочется ставить много запятых.

Так как быть? Или возможно и такое решение (одна запятая)?

Comment: Как же вы любите оправдывать ошибки... Посмотрите "Адвокат дьявола".

Comment: Я не оправдывала, так как  надеялась, что это сделаете вы или предложите другой, более удачный вариант.  Но если нет, то придется все-таки попробовать мне. Будем считать, что «причем» придает присоединительный характер всему обороту «причем в отличие от Горького», то есть это единая конструкция. Как вам такая идея? Можете доказать, что это невозможно или найти правило, не допускающее такое объединение?

Comment: Я про стремление оправдать. Вы про идею Nektoid? Поверьте, причина только в том, что там нет паузы. То есть авторская пунктуация. Автор не хочет ставить формальную запятую, либо же не по правилам ориентируется, а чувствует, где необходим знак, а при таком подходе пунктуация не может совпадать со всеми правилами.

Comment: Автор – может быть, но мне самой нравится эта конструкция, вот я и хочу ее «оправдать», выражаясь вашими словами. Иначе говоря, я предполагаю, что она верна по грамматике,  а не только по интонации, то есть вписывается в  общие правила. А вы можете доказать обратное?  А Горький был, конечно,  важной персоной, но только не Очень Важной Персоной, то есть  более мелкого масштаба. Что вы там увидели нелогичного, я не понимаю.

Comment: oleedd, у вас одни эмоции (звучит или не звучит,  по-русски или не по-русски), а я ведь спрашиваю вполне конкретно. Почему я не могу использовать совместно  союз "причем" и  оборот "в отличие от"?  Какое правило мне запрещает это сделать?  Кажется, этот присоединительный союз используется в обособленных оборотах без  особых проблем. А чем этот оборот хуже? Здесь есть грамматические нарушения или какие-то еще ограничения?  Попробуйте расширить свое сознание.

Comment: Только что стилистика плохая. Оно плохо сочетается.

Comment: @Sharon Я могу понять-принять авторскую пунктуацию. Собственно, на то он и автор, чтобы расставлять знаки — сообразно своему виденью. Но ведь в этом-то предложении (оно чуть дальше представленного) *хоть где-нибудь* должна ведь быть запятая? **В тридцатые годы Сталин прилагал большие усилия для того чтобы понравиться западным писателям.**

Comment: @Римма Михайлова, А я разве возражаю? Конечно, запятая нужна,  не знаю, куда он ее дел. :) Мне интересны те вопросы,  которые имеют нестандартное решение, а это ошибка корректора.

Comment: @oleedd
Итак, вы считаете такую грамматику корректной? Ну а стилистика – это дело вкуса. С интонацией проблем тоже нет – союз можно интонационно подчеркнуть при желании. Ваш ответ: такое решение возможно. Остается только оформить ответ и получить вознаграждение.

Comment: У меня уже появились сомнения. Пока просто не исключаю вариант, что грамматика правильная. *Ну а стилистика – это дело вкуса* — если чуть-чуть не нравится, то да, а если сильно — то нет, значит, есть проблемы. В этом предложении опять же нет паузы (если произнести "для того чтобы" цельно), как и запятой. Порой в таких случаях её не ставят.

Comment: Низзя! Нет никаких оснований не ставить  запятую перед "для того чтобы". Не стоит забывать о том, что грамматика дает нам  основной (базовый) ответ,  а интонация только корректирует варианты при их наличии (хотя часто именно это определяет окончательный ответ).  Не будете же вы считать это  предложение устойчивым оборотом с подчинительным союзом. А иного не дано.

Comment: Не будем забывать о том, что человек, не знающий правила, поставит запятую, если есть пауза. Так и корректор, не знающий, что запятая должна стоять.

Comment: Это же все-таки официально изданная книга, а не записи в Сети.  Можно пропустить ошибку, а вот не знать невозможно. Иначе это будет профессиональное несоответствие. Даже в регионах редакторы стараются следовать правилам, а это московское издательство.

Comment: Сейчас полно такого профессионального несоответствия. Допустим, человек по знакомству попал куда-то. Или, допустим, просто повезло.

Comment: Сейчас кончилась эпоха знакомств. Крупные издательства поглотили мелкие и организовали процесс по европейским стандартам.  За прозрачными стенками, одно рабочее место на двоих, да еще экзамен на соответствие каждые полгода.  Не сдал - до свидания! А иначе не выживешь, все поставили на поток.  Какое уж там знакомство - это все в прошлом.   Но эта книга  издательства "Альпина", может, там пока еще не все так строго.

Comment: Почему же везде так много ошибок? Часто в продвинутых вещах, от незнания.

Comment: Москва здесь липовая, оказывается. Отпечатано с готовых файлов заказчика в г. Ульяновске. Бумага газетная, обложка невыразительная, а денег много попросили...

Comment: @Sharon строго говоря, где отпечатано — дело десятое. Все издательства заключают договор с типографиями, последние лишь печатают с того макета, который прислали. Редактура, корректура и вёрстка — это работа издательства. Мелких издательств ОЧЕНЬ много, погуглите — удивитесь. Правда, преимущественно таких, которые не занимаются логистикой и продажами продукта, а просто предоставляют пакет издательских услуг, по итогу вручая автору за его деньги готовый тираж. А уж продажами автор сам занимается, если ему это вообще надо.

Comment: Значит, все вопросы к Ольге Равданис, менеджеру проектов и редактору издательства «Альпина Паблишер» (Дата основания: 1998 г.) В составе холдинга два издательства: «Альпина Паблишер» и «Альпина нон-фикшн».  Из интервью:
 От российских авторов мы получаем через сайт порядка 600 заявок в год, и берем в работу 5-6 книг из этого объема. Отсев происходит колоссальный.
(Вот куда принес свою книгу Б. Акунин.)

Comment: Сборник «Русские в Англии» выходит в свет в конце октября 2021 года сразу в трех форматах: в бумажном, электронном и в аудиоформате.«В издательстве «Альпина Паблишер» она выйдет в обычном, бумажном виде, с картинками. Обложка — ностальгическая. Все мы вышли из серой бонковской  шинели (Наталья Бонк – автор знаменитого учебника английского языка, его обложка и стала прототипом обложки бумажной версии книги Акунина ).

Comment: Можете с ними связаться и спросить, почему они такие безграмотные: https://alpinabook.ru/contacts/ Контактов самого Акунина не удалось найти

Comment: Писатель Борис Акунин живет в Лондоне уже 5 лет, вот и неудивительно, что с ним трудно связаться. Но вы все-таки попробуйте. Вопрос о причинах безграмотности  будет выглядеть риторическим. Но можно поработать с издательством  на общественных началах – присылать примеры, где присутствуют явные ошибки,  с обоснованием корректного написания. Возможно, вас пригласят тогда в штатные сотрудники. :)  А почему бы и нет? Может,  это как раз тот случай, когда "просто повезло".

Answer (score 2):

1. В Нацкорпусе можно найти **оба варианта оформления**:

***Причем в отличие от других аналогичных мероприятий**, участники будут освобождены от уплаты предварительного взноса…* [Сергей Татаренков, 2002]

*Причем, **в отличие от современного спорта,** и йогой и боевыми искусствами можно достаточно серьезно заниматься практически в любом возрасте.* [Олег Васильев, 2003.12]

*Причём, **в отличие от него**, обожаю всяческие застолья, гостей, весёлые и продолжительные разговоры.* [И. Э. Кио. Иллюзии без иллюзий (1995-1999)]
Вариант с постановкой запятой после союза встречается чаще.

Таким образом, можно сделать **выводы:**

1. В правилах нет ограничений на эту тему, то есть присоединительный союз «причем» может относиться к обособленному обстоятельственному обороту на общих основаниях.
2. Решение зависит **от структуры  и распространенности предложения** и   является факультативным (авторским).  Подобное правило действует при расчленении составных подчинительных союзов.

Comment: Я согласен с допустимостью этих двух вариантов пунктуации (и соотв. интонации), поэтому не привожу отдельного ответа. Но они различаются смысловым акцентом, который делается либо на отличии от ситуации с Горьким (без первой запятой), либо на уточнении "масштаба важности" (обособленный оборот, переставляемый в другие части предложения без изменения оттенков смысла). Поэтому "авторский" выбор не должен быть _произвольным_, для пущей "художественности".

Comment: Вариант с одной запятой мне видится уместным лишь в случае упоминания Горького в предшествующем контексте: акцент на Горьком больше напоминает отсылку к уже сказанному, чем вновь вводимый пример.

Comment: Спасибо, Alex_ander, за ваш комментарий. Он, как мне кажется, касается семантической темы при выборе знака, а эта тема здесь практически вообще не ставилась. Я внимательно прочитала ваши рассуждения, но не уверена в том, то согласна с вашими выводами. Поэтому было бы неплохо, если бы вы дали ОТДЕЛЬНЫЙ ОТВЕТ – может быть, другие участники подключились бы к обсуждению.

Comment: О Горьком в предыдущем тексте было сказано достаточно, чтобы изобразить его масштабной личностью.  И вот теперь автор хочет сказать, что личность Уэллса кажется ему более значимой. Мне думается, что тогда « в отличие от Горького» нужно обособить с двух сторон, но вы вроде бы считаете иначе.

Comment: Если о Горьком ранее говорилось, то вариант без первой запятой _тоже_ возможен; автор мог его выбрать, если для него важнее было акцентировать сравнение "текущего" персонажа с ранее упоминавшимся, чем сопоставление двух "масштабов значения".

Comment: Спасибо. Думаю, что акцент именно на масштабности личности Уэллса. До этого автора перечислял предыдущие связи Муры с известными людьми, и в в том числе с  Горьким.

Answer (score 1):

Если рассматривать этот вопрос как разминку для ума, то вот Вам изобретательная трактовка: первая часть второго предложения — парцелляционно отделённая часть первого предложения, соединённая запятой с изначальным вторым предложением. Восстановим теоретически возможный первоначальный вид: *В период между мировыми войнами он был Очень Важной Персоной, причем в отличие от Горького. Персоной* [он был] *не национального, а планетарного значения.*

Comment: Спасибо за изобретательность!  Я бы немного подправила  вашу конструкцию (вроде бы связки не хватает):  В период между мировыми войнами он был Очень Важной Персоной, причем в отличие от Горького.  То есть персоной не национального, а планетарного значения.  Но, пожалуй,  у Акунина все-таки лучше. Или нет?   Итак, на конкурс представлены три варианта...

Comment: Тогда получается, что Горький — не очень важная персона. Но персона национального значения тоже очень важная. Не сильно логично. Но хорошая попытка оправдать ошибку.